# Como e aonde validar controles de um formulário que correspondem aos campos da minha base de dados?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho o seguinte problema: Eu preciso validar meus controles (textbox, combobox, etc) que correspondem aos campos da minha tabela, por exemplo, na minha tela eu tenho o controle txtBairro, no qual os dados que serão inseridos ali serão persistidos no campo Bairro da minha tabela na base de dados.

Eu estou gerenciando meu banco via código (Code First) + Entity Framework, no qual mapeei usando engenharia reversa. Se no mapeamento da minha base de dados eu já tenho validações (Fluent API e DataAnnotations), eu não deveria validar os controles do meu form novamente, pois seria retrabalho. A questão que me surge é a seguinte: como eu posso usar essas validaçoes que o próprio framework me proporcionou com a engenharia reversa para validar os controles do meu form também?

Comment: Vamos por partes... se foi feita uma "engenharia reversa" é DB First, quem veio antes?
Que tipo de aplicação é? como está fazendo o bind da model com os controles? Edite sua pergunta apresentando um [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Abner,
A questão é mais ampla do que um simples retrabalho ao validar os campos antes de enviar ao banco. Imagine o trabalho por trás para fazer todas as informações chegarem até o banco de dados e serem validadas somente lá.

Validar dados no cliente evita que todo esse trabalho e ainda melhora a experiência do usuário final.

Você também tem que considerar o mais importante. Validar as regras de negócio. Para um CRUD simples você pode até considerar, mas para negócios complexos deve pensar no todo antes de definir a estratégia.

Se seu banco já tem as regras de validação, você terá esta validação. Tudo depende do tipo de projeto, perspectivas futuras, se for algo maior, com grande possibilidade de escalar, repense a estratégia.